# What spider species is this?

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

[image]

I saw this spider yesterday and it was the first time I saw one. It had a log slender body and an almost tail like end. It also can apparently jump. Just wanted to know what species this is. Location (Cavite, Philippines)

Comment: Please provide your location and the approximate size of the spider. It'll ensure you get an accurate answer. Thank you.

Comment: Definitely a pike slinder jumper. Location and size will help with species ID.

Answer (score 2):

It's one of the more unusual Jumping Spiders - similar, as Charles [said above](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/79478/what-spider-species-is-this#comment141570_79478), to the North American spider *Marpissa pikei*, the Slender Jumping Spider (see second link below).  Yours is even thinner and more stretched out, but still clearly a Jumping Spider, from the long, heavy front legs and the big eyes on the front of its head.
Your species appears to be a spider called *Mantisatta logicauda* (first link below)

[image]

http://www.peckhamia.com/salticidae/diagnost/mantisat/longi-ph.htm

http://bugeric.blogspot.com/2012/07/spider-sunday-pike-slender-jumper.html